# Run cosmos scope script in ADF V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to run cosmos scope script in ADF pipeline.
Scope script takes input parameter

> 1. current date
> 2. folder path.

My challenge is how can I read and call the parameters in my scope script(I am using scope activity).

Answer (score 0):

To read parameters into your scope script, insert these two lines in the .script file

```
#DECLARE Path string = "@@PathParameterName@@";
#DECLARE Date string = "@@DateParameterName@@";
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these 2 parameters as scope script parameters.
Once you load the script in ADF under the activity in advanced you should see those parameters.
Then you can pass in the static/dynamic values to these parameters from ADF scope activity.